# Dynamic Pivoting in SQL - Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have an input file

```
Customer    PhoneNum      Location    Brand
John        1234          ABC         Oppo
John        1234          DEF         MI
John        1234          KLM         RealMe
John        1234          LKM         1+
Joe         9934          ABC         Apple
Joe         9934          DEF         Samsung
```

The same phone number can be listed to multiple phone brands and the number of brands per phone number can be dynamic i.e. some can have 2 brands some can have 4 some 8 etc. I can pass the list of unique brands in the pivot query but that would create columns which might not have values.

the result i want is

````
Customer PhoneNum      Brand1   Brand1Location    Brand2    Brand2Location   Brand3    Brand3Location  Brand4   Brand4Location
John     1234           Oppo    ABC                 MI      DEF             RealMe      KLM             1+       LKM
Joe      9934           Apple   ABC               Samsung   DEF
```
Here i dont need the list of brands but if i know the maximum record per number is say 4 i can have the output in above format, which I believe is a good way to read the result. 

Is there any way in SQL to get the above result. 

select * from phone_multiple_make 
pivot(max(location),max(brand) for brand in 
      ('MI','Oppo','RealMe') )as p;
````

Answer (score 1):

[image]
If you're ok with not using a pivot function you can acheive your results like this:

```
WITH CTE AS ( 
SELECT 'John' CUSTOMER,1234 PHONENUM,'ABC' LOCATION,'Oppo' BRAND         
UNION
SELECT 'John' CUSTOMER,1234 PHONENUM,'DEF' LOCATION,'MI' BRAND UNION
SELECT 'John' CUSTOMER,1234 PHONENUM,'KLM' LOCATION,'RealMe' BRAND UNION
SELECT 'John' CUSTOMER,1234 PHONENUM,'LKM' LOCATION,'1+' BRAND UNION
SELECT 'Joe' CUSTOMER,9934 PHONENUM,'ABC' LOCATION,'Apple' BRAND UNION
SELECT 'Joe' CUSTOMER,9934 PHONENUM,'DEF' LOCATION,'Samsung' BRAND   )
SELECT CUSTOMER, PHONENUM
,J:BRAND1:BRAND::STRING BRAND1, J:BRAND1:LOCATION::STRING LOCATION1 
,J:BRAND2:BRAND::STRING BRAND2, J:BRAND2:LOCATION::STRING LOCATION2
,J:BRAND3:BRAND::STRING BRAND3, J:BRAND3:LOCATION::STRING LOCATION3
,J:BRAND4:BRAND::STRING BRAND4, J:BRAND4:LOCATION::STRING LOCATION4
FROM ( 
SELECT CUSTOMER, PHONENUM, OBJECT_AGG(KEY,OBJ) J FROM (  
SELECT CUSTOMER, PHONENUM
,'BRAND'||ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY CUSTOMER,PHONENUM ORDER BY BRAND)::STRING KEY
,OBJECT_CONSTRUCT( 'LOCATION', LOCATION, 'BRAND',BRAND)   OBJ FROM  CTE) GROUP BY 1,2)
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to make the query dynamic as in we dont provide the brand1, brand2 etc and it dynamically creates those columns like it does in Pivot.